# Best video container that can accept extra meta data

Tags: video, avi, ogg, mkv, matroska

I'm developping a software that can generate some video with different codec (H.264, MJPEG...). I would like my video readable with VLC, but i want ability to add some extra information in the video file for each frame (for example timestamp) and for the global video (a verified signature).

I would the file working with VLC but ignoring these meta information. But my custom player will be able to read them and display these information.

Anyone can tell me which container will be the best to do that?

I'm using AVI for now but it doens't seems to support this. I read few part on the Matroska container (MKV) that seems to be able to do that but i'm not really sure.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The mp4 container can include XMP (Extensible Metadata Platform) information:

- http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp.html

There is a free software tool which focuses on writing metadata of all kinds to different file types - it would be a good starting point for you:

- http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: Thank you, but i guess it's for global metadata and not per frame metadata?

Comment: The XMP spec includes the concept of markers which allows info to be associated against a specific frame count in a given track. You can also specify how many frames you want the info to relate to. The concept is similar to subtitle tracks in a container where you have the subtitle information in a separate stream in the container. XMP is now an ISO spec and seems to require payment to view but there is more info on these concepts here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart2.pdf

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I will try this and post the feedbak.